# VS Code How to Jump OUT of a bracket

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscodevim

In the middle of a pair of brackets, I want to move the cursor OUT of the bracket. That is

```
(This is some| text) --> (This is some text)|
```

I notice that there is a `Go to Bracket` command which moves the cursor TO the bracket, i.e.,

```
(This is some| text) --> (This is some text|)
```

In this simple example, simply chaining this command with a TabOut would do the trick. However, in some more complicated examples (like `\left(\right)` in LaTeX), TabOut will not work.

Also, Vim command `]%` will solve the problem; but it doesn't work in VS Code.

---

Edit: the plugin pointed out by `@rioV8` is very helpful. However, the simple regex moves **after the next bracket**, instead of moving **out of the current scope**. Consider a more complicated example:

```
# vim command ]%a
(This |is {some} text) -> (This is {some} text)|

# Select By plugin
(This |is {some} text) -> (This is {some}| text)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the extension [Select By](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.select-by#move-by)

Define the following key binding:

```
  {
    "key": "ctrl+f6",  // or any other key combo
    "when": "editorTextFocus",
    "command": "moveby.regex",
    "args": {
      "regex": "\\)",
      "properties": ["next", "end"]
    }
  }
```